# eaccelerator PHP error

Tags: plugins, php

I installed a Wordpress plugin and I'm getting the following error. The weird thing is I checked the plugins' source and I really don't understand why it would need those scripts.

> [30-May-2011 11:10:03] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/eaccelerator.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 [30-May-2011 11:10:03] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ffmpeg.so' - /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

This is the plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/upprev-nytimes-style-next-post-jquery-animated-fly-in-button/

Comment: Whats the plugin? it will help those that want to help you if they can take a look at it themselves..

Comment: This is the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/upprev-nytimes-style-next-post-jquery-animated-fly-in-button/

Comment: are you sure its the plugin and not some other code or plugin you used

Comment: The error_log is located in the plugins' folder and that's why I supposed it's caused by the plugin. But could you please let me know what could cause that error ?

Comment: Does disabling plugin make error go away? Had you tried asking your hosting support about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages have nothing to do with your plugins or WordPress.  Those are from you PHP.ini file trying to load extensions that are either not there or in the wrong directory.  Usually caused when you upgrade version of PHP and don't change the extension directory.

If you have shell access run `$ php -V` to get more info.  If your on managed hosting call your host they can and will fix for you.